# How to get access token from Dropbox Sync & Datastore xamarin component

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I trying get an access token from  Dropbox Sync & Datastore xamarin component in Xamarin iOS project.I have used dropnet to get the access token but I'm getting an http exception :( let me know where I'm doing wrong

```
 private static void GetAccessToken()
    {
        try
        {

            const string DropboxSyncKey = "XXXXXXXX";
            const string DropboxSyncSecret = "XXXXXX";
           //this url is obtained fromDBAccountManager.SharedManager.HandleOpenURL(url);
            string token = "db-XXXXXX://1/connect?oauth_token_secret=XXXXXXX&state=xXXXXXXX&uid=XXXXXX&oauth_token=xXXXXXXXX";
            token = token.Substring(token.LastIndexOf("&") + 13);
            string stoken = "db-XXXXXX://1/connect?oauth_token_secret=XXXXXXX&state=xXXXXXXX&uid=XXXXXX&oauth_token=xXXXXXXXX";
            int indexof = stoken.IndexOf("?") + 20;
            int lastindex = stoken.IndexOf("&") - indexof;
            string secrettoken = stoken.Substring(indexof, lastindex);
            var client = new DropNetClient(DropboxSyncKey, DropboxSyncSecret, token, secrettoken);
            var accesskey = client.GetAccessToken();
            Console.WriteLine(token);
            Console.WriteLine(secrettoken);
            Console.WriteLine(accesskey);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the actual exception you get?

Comment: Also, I don't think you want to call `GetAccessToken`. You already have the OAuth token and secret, so you should be able to just start using the client. E.g. `client.Account_Info()`

Comment: I'm getting object reference not set to instance exception so i have used this code `  DropNetClient client = new DropNetClient(apikey, apisecretkey, usertoken, usersecrettoken);` still the same exception.

Comment: Please share the full exception, including the stack trace.

Comment: I have resolved the object reference exception now i got this one DropBoxIntegration[3831:508119] Stack Trace at DropNet.DropNetClient.Execute (ApiType apiType, IRestRequest request) [0x0002c]

Comment: Is that really the full exception and stack trace that you're seeing? That amount of information isn't going to help. (We don't even know what line of your code is triggering it.)

Comment: 2015-05-25 22:43:22.081 DropBoxIntegration[401:63388] The annoying exception is Exception of type 'DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException' was thrown.
[0:] The annoying exception is Exception of type 'DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException' was thrown.
[0:] 
2015-05-25 22:43:22.501 DropBoxIntegration[401:63388] Stack Trace   at DropNet.DropNetClient.Execute (ApiType apiType, IRestRequest request) [0x0002c] in e:XXXXXXXX\Dropnet\DropNet-master\DropNet\Client\Client.cs:168 
  at DropNet.DropNetClient.GetAccessToken () [0x0005c] in e:XXXXXXXX\Dropnet\DropNet-master\DropNet\Client\User.Sync.cs:49

Comment: at DropBoxIntegration.DropboxViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x000b1] in e:XXXXXXXX\DropboxViewController.cs:39 
[0:] Stack Trace   at DropNet.DropNetClient.Execute (ApiType apiType, IRestRequest request) [0x0002c] in e:XXXXXXXX\DropNet-master\DropNet\Client\Client.cs:168 
  at DropNet.DropNetClient.GetAccessToken () [0x0005c] in e:XXXXXXXX\Dropnet\DropNet-master\DropNet\Client\User.Sync.cs:49 
  at DropBoxIntegration.DropboxViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x000b1] in e:XXXXXXXX\DropBoxIntegration\DropBoxIntegration\DropboxViewController.cs:39

Comment: This is the what i get in stack trace !

Comment: As I said before, don't call `GetAccessToken`. You already have an access token.